# c# avoiding boxing and repeated code

Tags: c#, oop, interface, func, boxing

I have below base class and derived classes. There are 2 points where I feel my code has problems:

```
public class FieldCollection
{
    public FieldCollection()
    {
        Fields = new List<FieldBase>();
    }

    public List<FieldBase> Fields { get; set; }

    public void InitFieldList()
    {
        foreach (var item in DbFieldList)
        {
            if (item.Type == FieldTypes.int)
            {
                Fields.Add(new Field<int>());
            }
            else
             if (item.Type == FieldTypes.string)
            {
                Fields.Add(new Field<string>());
            }
            ...
        };
    }

    public void SetFieldValue(string fieldName, object value)
    {
        FieldBase field = FindField(fieldName);

        if ((field as FInt) != null)
        {
            (field as FInt).SetValue(Convert.ToInt32(value));
        }
        else
        if ((field as FString) != null)
        {
            (field as FString).SetValue(Convert.ToString(value));
        }
        else
        if ((field as FDate) != null)
        {
            (field as FDate).SetValue(Convert.ToDateTime(value));
        };
    }

    public FieldBase FindField(string fieldName)
    {
        FieldBase field = Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => (String.Equals(f.Name, fieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));

        return field;
    }
}

public abstract class FieldBase
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}

public class FInt : FieldBase
{
    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
    }
}

public class FString : FieldBase
{
    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
    }
}

public class FDate : FieldBase
{
    public void SetValue(DateTime value)
    {
    }
}
```

1. Repeating: If the future there appears a new derived class then I will have to add additional if statement and so on.

> ```
> if ((field as FInt) != null)
> {
>     (field as FInt).SetValue(Convert.ToInt32(value));
> }
> else
> if ((field as FString) != null)
> {
>     (field as FString).SetValue(Convert.ToString(value));
> }
> else
> if ((field as FDate) != null)
> {
>     (field as FDate).SetValue(Convert.ToDateTime(value));
> };
> ```

2. Boxing and unboxing: I am forced to convert object value to desired type based on derived class's type:

> ```
> (field as FInt).SetValue(Convert.ToInt32(value));
> (field as FString).SetValue(Convert.ToString(value));
> (field as FDate).SetValue(Convert.ToDateTime(value));
> ```

I am interested in how to design these classes in order to overcome above mentioned problems.

Your help highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need generics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve both problems at once (code duplication and boxing) by rewriting your code using generics:

```
public class FieldCollection
{
    public FieldCollection()
    {
        Fields = new List<FieldBase>();
    }

    public List<FieldBase> Fields { get; set; }

    public void SetFieldValue<T>(string fieldName, T value)
    {
        var field = FindField<T>(fieldName);

        field.SetValue(value);
    }

    public Field<T> FindField<T>(string fieldName)
    {
        return Fields.OfType<Field<T>>()
            .FirstOrDefault(f => (String.Equals(f.Name, fieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
    }
}

public abstract class FieldBase
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}

public class Field<T> : FieldBase
{
    public void SetValue(T value)
    {
    }
}
```

For `InitFieldList`, you can use a dictionary of lambdas. For instance:

```
private Dictionary<FieldTypes, Func<FieldBase>> FieldInitializers = new Dictionary<FieldTypes, Func<FieldBase>>
{
    { FieldTypes.int, () => new Field<int>() },
    { FieldTypes.string, () => new Field<string>() }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of browsing your dictionary:

```
public void InitFieldList()
{
    foreach (var item in DbFieldList)
    {
        Fields.Add(FieldInitializers[item.Type].Invoke());
    }
}
```